# Подмена URL в HTACCESS по REQUEST параметрам

Tags: javascript, php, url

Пример на js
Наша ссылка для примера: http://example.com/name-razdel/?module=shop&action=search&cat_id=0&a=&pr1=0&pr2=100&brand%5B%5D=22

```
var url = window.location.href;
var partUrl = url.split('&brand%5B%5D=');
if (partUrl[1] == "19") window.history.pushState(null, null, "/" + url.split('/')[3] + "/ctec-happy-hair-braziliya/"); 
if (partUrl[1] == "20") window.history.pushState(null, null, "/" + url.split('/')[3] + "/felps-profissional-braziliya/");
```

То есть:
 1. Получаем URL_REQUEST
 2. Разбиваем строку по бренду
 3. При выполнении условия меняем подменяем url

Суть в том, что через JS это палевно, url меняется после отдачи страницы, а не до.

#### UPD

Вот то, что я пробовал и и многое другое, мой ответ тому Ипанатию, только тут в нормальном отображении :-)

Я попросил помощи в решении с htaccess, потому что я уже в нём всё перепробовал.

Вот пример:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/keratin$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand%5B%5D=19$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /keratin/ctec-happy-hair-braziliya/? [R=301,L]
```

Но это не помогает сделать редирект с такого урл с гет параметрами:

```
/keratin/?module=shop&action=search&cat_id=0&a=&pr1=0&pr2=0&brand%5B%5D=19
```

На страницу брэнда

```
/keratin/ctec-happy-hair-braziliya/
```

Comment: В целом ипатьев вам верный ход мыслей дал, это надо делать на уровне php, а не htaccess. Откуда htaccess узнает, что url у страницы - ctec-happy-hair-braziliya....

Comment: Александр, на сколько я знаю, задаётся условие, по которому и htaccess должен перенаправить на нужный url в случае если условие подходит.

На уровне PHP это слишком легко. Ещё больше лёгкости на JS

Comment: Как htaccess поймёт куда его редиректить?  Откуда он возьмёт ctec-happy-hair-braziliya ?

Comment: Либо вы хотите чисто одну страницу средиректить, то вам подойдёт обычный 301 редрирект

Comment: Жаль ссылку потерял, где синим по белому написано, что
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Условие
RewriteRule [ШАБЛОН] [Куда перенаправить в случае если условие подходит] [R=301,L]

Comment: Мне надо порядка 30 страниц редиректить

Comment: Вы не в ту сторону смтотрите. Ещё раз я повторю: откуда htaccess узнает о ctec-happy-hair-braziliya ?

Comment: Хорошо я Вас понял. Попробую простым редиректом.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала следует прочесть вот этот [классический друд](http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke).

После этого живо себе представить себе два условных квадратика - сервер и браузер. Внутри серверного квадратика пририсовать маленький квадратик htaccess, и после этого попытаться расположить на этой схеме свой алгоритм,

> 1. Получаем URL_REQUEST 2. Разбиваем строку по бренду 3. При выполнении условия меняем подменяем url

После того как это не получится, придется придумать что-то другое:

1. (на сервере, в РНР скрипте) получаем URL_REQUEST
2. разбиваем строку по бренду, формируем новый урл
3. Говорим браузеру, чтобы он запросил новый урл
4. браузер запрашивает у сервера новый урл
5. на сервере htaccess превращает новый урл обратно в старый, добавляя какой-нибудь параметр, который скажет РНР что на этот раз надо не делать редирект а обработать запрос
6. РНР генерирует страницу

Comment: Ну я даже и не знаю, что на это сказать. Фэспалм наверное.
Вот никакого хорошего ответа от Вас уважаемый.

Я попросил помощи в решении с htaccess, потому что я уже в нём всё перепробовал.

Вот пример:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/keratin$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^brand%5B%5D=19$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /keratin/ctec-happy-hair-braziliya/? [R=301,L]  

Но это не помогает сделать редирект с такого урл с гет параметрами:
/keratin/?module=shop&action=search&cat_id=0&a=&pr1=0&pr2=0&brand%5B%5D=19
На страницу брэнда
/keratin/ctec-happy-hair-braziliya/